# using Eval of ASP Listview as an inline CSS value

Tags: asp.net, listview, warnings, eval

my code is :

```
<asp:ListView ID="lst1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width:<%#Eval("Rating")%>%">
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

It works great, but in VisualStudio editor it's considered as invalid.
Is there any way to make it valid?

I know that I can create the whole ' style="width:xxx%" ' in the Eval but I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div style='<%# Eval("Rating", "width:{0}%") %>'></div>
```

it would make it accepted by the editor, I don't know what else you could do though.